# Dynamically call a static function?

Tags: php, function, static

Could someone fill in the blank. I need to call a static function on a class. Do I need to use eval here?

```
// Some settings require function calls
$switch = array ('random_image' => 'Splashpage::get_random_image()', 'splash_photos_count' => 'Splashpage::count_splash_photos()');
foreach($switch as $key => $function) {
    if ($name == $key) {
        return ... $function
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone has been partly right.

Firstly this array is wrong.

```
$switch = array ('random_image' => 'Splashpage::get_random_image()', 'splash_photos_count' => 'Splashpage::count_splash_photos()');
```

It should be:

```
$switch = array ('random_image' => 'Splashpage::get_random_image', 'splash_photos_count' => 'Splashpage::count_splash_photos');
```

This allows you to call - as 2 people have said - call_user_func and bobs your uncle.

```
$switch = array ('random_image' => 'Splashpage::get_random_image', 'splash_photos_count' => 'Splashpage::count_splash_photos');
if(isset($switch[$name])) {
    return call_user_func($switch[$name]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have PHP 5.2.3 or later, `call_user_func()` will work with static methods passed in that format:

```
foreach($switch as $key => $function) {
    if ($name == $key) {
        return call_user_func($function);
    }
}
```

Also, if you're going to return the result of the method call right away, you should not need a loop since that if condition will only get one chance to evaluate on true:

```
if (isset($switch[$name]) && is_callable($switch[$name])) {
    return call_user_func($switch[$name]);
}
```

Comment: method_exists requires 2 parameters, not one.

Answer (score 1):

Use the call_user_func function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

Example:

```
call_user_func('myClassName::'.$function);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you will always call those methods on the same class you could only put method names in your array and then call them like this:

```
$switch = array ('random_image' => 'get_random_image', 'splash_photos_count' => 'count_splash_photos');
foreach($switch as $key => $function) {
    if ($name == $key) {
        return Splashpage::$function ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently I only need Splashpage is the only class required but I think in the future this will change. Thank though.